# Solve: $\cos^2{x} > \sin^2{x}$

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

I want to solve: $$\cos^2{x} > \sin^2{x}$$ I am not quite sure how to go about it.

I was thinking something along those lines:
$$ \cos^2{x} > \sin^2{x} $$
$$ \cos^2{x} > 1 - \cos^2{x} $$
$$ 2\cos^2{x} > 1 $$
$$ \ln(2\cos^2{x}) > 0 $$
$$ 2\ln(2\cos{x}) > 0 $$

But I am stuck here and I am not sure this is the direction to go.

Comment: For your consideration, the last step contains two mistakes of algebra. $$\ln(2\cos^2x)=2\ln\lvert\cos x\rvert+\ln2$$ (for $\cos x\ne 0$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\cos^2x>\sin^2x\iff\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x>0$$

$$\iff2n\pi-\dfrac\pi2<2x<2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Could you please expand on the last step? Is there any trick to see that $\cos{2x}$ is in this interval: $2n\pi-\dfrac\pi2<2x<2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$ ?

Comment: @Mykybo, See http://www.math-only-math.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule.html

Comment: ohh, totaly forgot that we are looking for the interval in which $\cos{2x}$ is positive, totally makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Another approach is to divide both sides by $\cos^2(x)$ to get
$$
\tan^2(x)\lt1
$$
or equivalently
$$
-1\lt\tan(x)\lt1
$$
Remember that $\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

solve $$(\cos(x)-\sin(x))(\cos(x)+\sin(x))>0$$

Comment: Simpler? How? $ $

Comment: you didn't see it?

Comment: to be honest I don't see it either, could you please explain?

Comment: Gambit failed, Graubner.

Answer (score 0):

Hint see the graph of cos is decreasing function sarting from $1$ at 0 degrees uptil $45$ degrees while sin graph is an increasing function $0-45$ degrees . Now as it is square it will never go below zeeo but oscillate similarly between $0-1$ thus $cos^2(x)>sin^2(x)$ in the interval $[0,45)$